# When I use warp,it just work on localhost, but not public network

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I wrote a Web application based on rust-warp,it works well.But it can just access by localhost:3030(127.0.0.1:3030).Now I want to access it by public network(101.35.56.79)/Local Area Network(192.168.1.18),but it didn't work.I can't find the relevant information to this problem.Here's my code:

```
    //#![deny(warnings)]
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
#![allow(unused)]

use warp::Filter;
use warp::body::json;
use warp::reply;

use serde_json::json;

// struct Article{
//     articleTitle: String,
//     articleText: String,
// }
// struct ArticleList {
//     articles: Vec<Article>,
// }

#[tokio::main]

async fn main() {
    println!("Welcome to little guy's sever console!");
    //展示主页
    //let show_HomePage = warp::fs::dir("../");
    //成功连接后发送一条欢迎信息
    let say_hello = 
        warp::path::end().map(|| {
            println!("Someone connected!");
            "Welcome to Little Guy's HomePage~
            try to visit ./HomePage.html".replace("    ", "")
        });
    //获取文章
    let get_article = 
        warp::path("getArticles")
        .and(warp::path::param())//参数是文章分区
        .map(|article_partition: String| {
            format!("The article_partition you request is: {}", article_partition);
            //let article_list = ArticleList{articles: vec![Article{articleTitle:String::from("title1"), articleText: String::from("text1"})]};
            //let article_list = articles{vec![{articleTitle: "tt1"},]};
            let article_list = json!({
                "articles":[
                    {
                        "articleTitle": "tt1",
                        "articleText": "text1",
                    },
                    {
                        "articleTitle": "tt2",
                        "articleText": "text2",
                    }
                ]
            });
            warp::reply::json(&article_list)
        });

    let get_introduction = 
        warp::path("getIntroduction")
        .map(||{
            let introduction = json!({
                "introduction": {
                    "introduction": "This is Little Guy's introduction",
                }
            });
            warp::reply::json(&introduction)
        });

    let routes = 
        //show_HomePage
        say_hello
        .or(get_article)
        .or(get_introduction);

    warp::serve(routes)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 80))
        .await;
}
```

I thought the problem is on

```
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 80))
        .await;
```

but I can't find more details about it in warp's document(https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/).I need your help,Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

你好。You are correct about where the error lies. In the provided code, the server is binding to `127.0.0.1` on port `80`. To make the server accessible from all interfaces, change the binding address to `0.0.0.0` for the same port. The new code should read.

```rust
warp::serve(routes)
    .run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 80))
    .await;
```